# Finding all words (or sentences) from html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to find all words within a block of html. Reading the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) I thought this was possible by using the `find('text')` function. Though I'm unable to get this to return anything.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/simple_html_dom.php';

$html = str_get_html("<html><body><div><p><span>Hello to the <b>World</b></span></p><p> again</p></div></body></html>");

foreach($html->find('text') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is to find all texts and their starting position within the html. For this particular example it would look like this:

```
[
    0 => [
        'word' => 'Hello to the ',
        'pos' => 27
    ],
    1 => [
        'word' => 'World',
        'pos' => 43
    ],
    2 => [
        'word' => ' again',
        'pos' => 66
    ]
]
```

So can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong with Simple HTML Dom and help me figure out the starting position of each word? Or tell me of another tool I should use?

Comment: I believe the parameter passed to the find command is an HTML element name. This library is very old and outdated. You'd be much better off using PHP's built-in methods, though you're going to have quite a challenge getting character positions.

Comment: I managed to get elements by using find('p') or find('span') but not with find text.

Comment: You might try one of the older versions and see if it is a bug in the new one and/or open a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

You can use available function`strip_tag`, `preg_match_all` to extract the position of each word

```
$str = "<html><body><div><p><span>Hello to the <b>World</b></span></p><p> again</p></div></body></html>";
$find =  '/'.str_replace(' ','|',strip_tags($str)).'/';
preg_match_all($find, strip_tags($str), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

Result :-

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Hello
                [1] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => to
                [1] => 6
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => the
                [1] => 9
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => World
                [1] => 13
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => again
                [1] => 19
            )

    )

)
```